# Jquery scrollto animation to specific coordinates

Tags: jquery, scrollto, scrolltop

So I'm trying to get a link to scroll to a certain coordinate (not an element) on the same page very slowly. I tried to look at the Jquery site but it seems the plugin site is down.

Can anyone supply a link embedded in an html sample source code as I don't know much about jquery.

[This is the link for the plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you dont need a plugin for that.. it might save you some overhead... please try this, i hope it adresses your issue

assuming you have the following link

```
<a id="button" href="#">click me</a>
```

add the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a#button').bind('click', function(event){
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: '100'
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: the code above will scroll the body 100 px  from the top... if you wish to make it slower add the 'slow' parameter as the last parameter of the animate function

Comment: $('body') needs to be $('html,body') or else it will not work in some browsers

Comment: When I use this code no matter what happens it just scrolls to the very top of the screen using no animation. I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: because you are probably not preventing the event.preventDefault and it actually links you back to the page

Comment: when you click on the link.. make sure that you are actually not allowing it to proceed with 'linking' by adding event.preventDefault() or e.preventDefault(); depending on the parameter you added for the click function...

Comment: if you dont do that.. it pretty much refreshes the page

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: if this doesnt work.. can you please post your link tag and also the click function?

Comment: Hooray it worked! I had no idea you had to put the code in the document that's using it. Thank you so much!

Comment: well you can put it in the actual document by adding a <script> tag but it would be better by actually creating a filename.js file and adding the tag <script src="filename.js"></script>

Comment: That's what I had at first but it didn't work. It only worked when I put the whole code into the header.